# Grails jQuery-UI In Assets

Tags: jquery, grails

my problem is that my application.js looks like this

```
//= require plugins/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js
//= require plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js
//= require spring-websocket
```

and the images are under assets/images/ . But when running the page the icons are missing because they are being searched under assets/images...

How to fix this problem? Any tips are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear from your description where images are supposed to be searched for, if not under `assets/images`?

Comment: Im very new to grails development. I put jquery-ui.js under assets/javascripts/ amd the css file under assets/stylesheets/ and the images under /assets/images/ . Is it correct? And this asset file with the requirements. I mean it's the jquery-ui plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All CSS images should have the same path relative to the `images` folder as they have to the css file in the library distribution.

For example, if your library contains the files:

```
├── img
│   └── image.png
└── styles.css
```

Then your assets should be located under:

```
└── assets
    ├── images
    │   └── img
    │       └── image.png
    └── stylesheets
        └── styles.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take another approach this to situation and suggest that you don't split up 3rd party libraries into the standard asset-pipeline folders.  I would create another root level directory that holds externally created libraries:

```
└── assets
    ├── images
    │   └── ...
    ├── stylesheets
    │   └── ...
    ├── javascripts
    │   └── ...
    └── vendor
         ├── jquery
         │
         ├── jquery-ui
         │
        ...
```

The asset-pipeline author (Bertram) even alludes to this on the [usage page](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html):

> A common folder that gets added to this set of organization is a "lib"
>   folder. This folder can be useful in organizing third party libraries
>   like jQuery, or Bootstrap.

It just feels wrong (and more work) to me to split external libraries to fit the asset-pipeline paradigm.